# Instantiating a class object with window[string]()

Tags: javascript, class

```
class Unit {
  constructor(){
  }
}    

var str = "Unit";
var a = new window[str](); // error
var b = new window["Unit"](); // error

var u = new Unit(); // works
    (u instanceof Unit) // true
```

I only recently made the switch to ES 6 syntax in regards to declaring classes. Im pretty sure that formerly i could instantiate a class like this, however ever since i have used "class" syntax, the instantiation of an object by windowclassName is not working anymore.

What exactly am i missing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables declared with `class` behave similarly to those declared with `const` and `let` - they do not get implicitly assigned to the window object (which is arguably a good thing). If you wanted to put `Unit` on `window`, you would have to do so explicitly:

```js
class Unit {
  constructor(){
    console.log('constructing');
  }
}    
window.Unit = Unit;

var str = "Unit";
var a = new window[str]();
```

You might consider using your own object of classes to avoid global pollution:

```js
const myClasses = {
  Unit: class Unit {
    constructor(){
      console.log('constructing');
    }
  }
};

var str = "Unit";
var a = new myClasses[str]();
```

Object values cannot reference each other while in the process of declaring an object literal - to put a subclass on `myClasses` that extends one of the existing classes, you'll have to do so outside of the `myClasses` declaration:

```js
const myClasses = {
  Unit: class Unit {
    constructor(){
      console.log('constructing');
    }
  }
};
myClasses.Child = class Child extends myClasses.Unit {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('Child running');
  }
}

var str = "Child";
var a = new myClasses[str]();
```

Comment: One follow up if i may. When i want to declare Subunit extends Unit with the class-holding object, it does not work. Is there some special treatment necesarry here, like assigning and declaring the Subunit only after all baseclasses are in fact loaded ?

Comment: See edit - you have to declare the child class after the `myClasses` object has finished being made.